# Firefox breaks word from slash

Tags: html, css, firefox, cross-browser

Why Firefox is breaking word from `/` (slash) and `-` (hyphen) into lines.

Example with `/` and `-`

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        LoremipsumdolorsitametconsecteturadipisicingelitLaboredistinctionamdoloresmodiamet/etblanditiisarchitectsundolorem/qnullobcaecatnobilibermollitia/sialiquiodiomagncommodi.

      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

---

Example without `/` and `-`

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        LoremipsumdolorsitametconsecteturadipisicingelitLaboredistinctionamdoloresmodiametetblanditiisarchitectsundoloremqnullobcaecatnobilibermollitiasialiquiodiomagncommodi.
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Both Examples are working good in other browsers, I have tried [`overflow-wrap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow-wrap) but didn't work.

I'm using Firefox `67.0 (64-bit)`.

Please open it in Firefox.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks as Mozilla is considering `/` and `-` as whitespace delimiters. After a small research I suggest escaping `/` and `-` with its html equivalent code, before emitting it to the table.

**UPDATE**
Found another pure CSS solution that works in mozilla too

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
}

table td { 
    word-break: keep-all; 
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        LoremipsumdolorsitametconsecteturadipisicingelitLaboredistinctionamdoloresmodiamet/etblanditiisarchitectsundolorem/qnullobcaecatnobilibermollitia/sialiquiodiomagncommodi.

      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Here is a small JS Snippet that escapes `/` and `-` to its equivalent html code.

```js
var str = 'Loremipsumdolorsitametconsectetura-dipisicingelitLaboredistinctionamdol-oresmodiamet/etblanditiisarchitectsundolorem/qnullobcaecatnobilibermollitia/sialiquiodiomagncommodi.';

const escaped = str.replace(/\//g, '&#47;').replace(/-/g, '&#45;');
```

Comment: I'm avoiding `JS` solution therefore I haven't tagged JS, as I'm facing this issue in entire project, and JS can slow down the UI/UX. Though I'm considering JS as last option.

Comment: I have updated the solution which is pure CSS and works in mozilla too.

Comment: Second Option works well, let's wait for some more good answers, else I'll go with yours.

Comment: @PiyushMarvaniya Ironically you have used same property in your answer, and saying that this answer is not working.

Comment: @AbhishekPandey - I have to try "keep-all" But not working fine

Answer (score 0):

Just add `word-break: keep-all;` to the td in CSS, works for me

Answer (score 0):

If the idea is to not break the line at all, then you can use `white-space: nowrap;`.

Answer (score -1):

You may want to try an HTML code for your forward slash and dash.

```html
For / use &#47;
For - use &#8211;
```

More info here: https://www.ascii.cl/htmlcodes.htm

Comment: it's dynamic content

Answer (score -1):

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
}
table tr td {
    word-break: break-all;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        LoremipsumdolorsitametconsecteturadipisicingelitLaboredistinctionamdoloresmodiamet/etblanditiisarchitectsundolorem/qnullobcaecatnobilibermollitia/sialiquiodiomagncommodi.
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: You have removed all slashes, you have removed problem instead of solving it.